# ComboBox and original value as an array

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a legacy MongoDB database (collection) where there is single value stored as an array List . But its only a one value that must be, in UI selected with ComboBox. So I have a model bean

```
class Project {
   List<Company> companies;
}
```

And I would like to bind it and edit with VAADIN ComboBox. Initialy I thought I can use some customer converter for ComboBox but can't get it to work. Combo should edit the first value in the List (Company bean) and store back into companies field as an array to remain compatible. Is it event possible to do it and if so can you give me some hint how to accomplish this?

**EDIT: Enhanced explanation**

MongoDB model:

```
 class Project {
       List<Company> companies;
    }
```

Vaadin UI:

```
ComboBox companies;
```

... 'companies' ComboBox is attached to BeanItemContainer which is List ... selection is therefore the only one Company bean, but should be stored, for compatibility reasons, as List with only one item. So basicly ComboBox should be able to read existing List value as single Company, allow selection and store it as List with this one selecten Company.

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to use a combo for one editable value? Because a text field would fit this purpose better... Either way, unless I'm missing something, you should be able to create an adapter between your model and what you want to display in the UI. Then when committing the changes, you automaticaly update your model bean

Comment: Combo is used beacuse values are selected from list of beans (class Company). What is adapter from Vaadin point of view?

Comment: I think you need to clearly explain what you want to do. Select a project? Select a company? Edit a company? Edit just first company? Edit list of companies? ComboBox cannot "edit" a value from the list. It just does selection.

Comment: Apologies, I was thinking more of a delegate rather then an adapter. Please see my answer below.

Comment: After reading your update I feel @sebgymn is correct and a bit more context is required. Are you trying to edit `Project` items while showing the `Company` as _read-only_? Adding some code may also help..

Answer (score 0):

### After the last question update the answer below may not be correct. Waiting for OP to provide details so the answer can be corrected.

---

<strike>You can use a sort of a [delegation approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(programming)#Design_pattern) using a `ProjectDelegator` wrapper. This will allow you to bind the form to the `Project` name (using the *project* field) as well as the `Company` name (using the *getCompany()* getter)</strike>

**1. The UI class**

```java
@PreserveOnRefresh
@SpringUI
public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        layout.setMargin(true);
        setContent(layout);

        // add the form to the UI
        layout.addComponent(new MyForm(new ProjectDelegator(new Project("myProject", new Company("myCompany")))));
    }
}
```

**2. The form**

```java
// "wrapping" the form in a custom component. not really needed but a nice touch
public class MyForm extends CustomComponent {
    public MyForm(ProjectDelegator projectDelegator) {
        FormLayout layout = new FormLayout();

        // use a binder to create fields and bind the members using reflection
        BeanFieldGroup<ProjectDelegator> binder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(ProjectDelegator.class);

        // bind the project name using the "project" field
        layout.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Project", "project.name"));

        // bind the company name using the "getCompany" method
        layout.addComponent(binder.buildAndBind("Company", "company.name"));

        // add a "save" button
        layout.addComponent(new Button("Save", new Button.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
                try {
                    // commit changes
                    binder.commit();
                } catch (FieldGroup.CommitException e) {
                    // didn't expect this! what gives?!
                    System.out.println("Could not save data: [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
                }
            }
        }));

        // set the delegator as the binder data source
        binder.setItemDataSource(projectDelegator);

        setCompositionRoot(layout);
    }
}
```

**3. The "delegator"**

```java
// delegator class to adapt from/to list with only 1 item
public class ProjectDelegator {
    // nice constant to express the intent as clearly as possible
    private static final int MY_ONLY_COMPANY = 0;

    // our delegate
    private Project project;

    public ProjectDelegator(Project project) {
        this.project = project;
    }

    // BeanFieldGroup will use this by reflection to bind the "company.name" field
    public Company getCompany() {
        // delegate the accessing to the origina product 
        return project.getCompanies().get(MY_ONLY_COMPANY);
    }

    // accessor; can if not required at a later time
    public Project getProject() {
        return project;
    }
}
```

**4. The legacy model classes**

```java
// our problem class
public class Project {
    private String name;
    private List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();

    public Project(String name, Company company) {
        this.name = name;
        companies.add(company);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Company> getCompanies() {
        return companies;
    }

    public void setCompanies(List<Company> companies) {
        this.companies = companies;
    }
}
```

```java
// the "indirect" problem :)
public class Company {
    private String name;

    public Company(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("Setting actual company name to [" + name + "]");
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**5. Resulting UI**

[image: Resulting interface]

**6. Pressing the save button**

`Setting actual company name to [myNewCompany]`